# Empty Spreadsheet holding onto space

Tags: excel, filesize

My users gave me a spreadsheet to research why our program wasn't able to import.

- I have been slowly dissecting it, and so far have deleted every single column and tab except for one.
- I have selected and deleted all cells and made sure there were none hidden.
- I have also checked that there is no code associated with the tab.

And yet, the file size is still 8 megs! If I create a new tab so I can delete the original, it then shrinks to a few k.

Where else could something be hiding in the tab to keep that size?

Comment: Takes me just past the data (L96) which is what i would expect.  If I delete all the data it oddly still takes me to that same cell!!!

Comment: Not sure.  Don't know where that is.  how do i get to it?

Comment: Ok, the selection pane did the trick.  There were a LOT of graphics that were moved up beyond the top cell (Had to be selected thru the pane, and then you could just see the bottom control dots)  Please put in a formal answer so i can give you the credit for teh answer.

Comment: **See VBA code to resolve this :** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003349/reduce-the-file-size-of-excel/9990499

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNTESTED!

Extraordinarily large (bytes) workbooks with very little apparent content are all too often created by data dumps into Excel.

One reason can be that the extraction code has been included with the data (check **Developer, Visual Basic**).

More likely to have a significant size impact is formatting, that can be detected by **Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special, Last cell** and observing the highlighted cell is a long way from the last ‘occupied’ cell. This can be fixed as below:

1. Select row immediately below the last ‘occupied’ row.
2. `Ctrl+Shift+Down`.
3. `Del`.
4. Save.

Size may also be increased by embedded objects (check **Editing, Find & Select, Selection Pane**) and also the content of Comments even where these are not displayed. [The specific answer to this question.]

Pivot tables with broken links may also be a cause.

Other causes can include the likes of the apparently blank ‘last cell’ indeed being occupied (say with a font colour to match the background) or other hidden objects.

Note that in all cases the file size may not reduce in response to ‘deletions’ until it is saved.

Comment: **I post answer on another question** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003349/reduce-the-file-size-of-excel/9990499

Comment: Just one quick note. If you are using Excel 2013 (not sure about anything else) you might need to select apparently empty rows or columns just as described and right click on rows or columns to delete them. Simply pressing delete did not work for me. But this method can really work, got 20MB+ workbook down to 700KB, so it is worth a try. Huge difference in performance.